# How do I use RegEx in a Twig/Timber filter?

Tags: php, regex, twig, timber

I'm trying to use `preg_replace` and a regex to remove the brackets `[` and `]` and all characters inside of them from the text output of a Twig v2 template using a Twig filter.

An example of the content output by Twig is

> An example of content is [caption id="attachment_4487"
>   align="alignright" width="500"] Lorem Ipsum caption blah
>   blah[/caption] and more content.

I want to remove everything inside the `[` and `]` brackets, leaving the `Lorem Ipsum caption blah blah`, as well as the `An example of content is`, etc.

The problem is that right now, I get no content displayed at all when the filter is used. The issue may be the filter construction for Twig; but I get no errors in the log. I've tested the regex at https://regex101.com/r/sN5hYk/1 but that could still be the issue.

The existing Twig filter https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html strips html, but doesn't strip brackets.

This is my filter function in functions.php:

```
add_filter('timber/twig', function($twig) {
   $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader());

   $twig->addFilter(
     new Twig_SimpleFilter(
       'strip_square_brackets', 

        function($string) {

            $string = preg_replace('\[.*?\]', '', $string);
            return $string;
}

 )
   );

   return $twig;
});
```

And the filter is called the standard way in the template.twig file:

`{{ content|strip_square_brackets }}`

Comment: Shouldn't that be: $string = preg_replace(/\[.*?\]/, '', $string);?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you replace a `string`, not a `regex`. Of course that string won't match.

Your line with Regex should look like:

```
$string = preg_replace(/\[.*?\]/, '', $string);
```

Now you're replacing a **regex match** with the empty string.

**Bonus Edit**:

The answer to your bonus question:

```
/\[.*?\].*\[.*?\]/
```

Basically it just doubles the match and matches everything in between.

An alternative, which is more robust, if you always use `'caption'`:

```
/\[caption.*/caption\]/
```

Comment: Well, that was easy :)  So are the `/` delimiters, or do they escape the `\`'s?

Comment: A Regex must be surrounded by two '/' in many regex flavors, strings are surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Interesting; I'm obviously learning this stuff. As a bonus (!), how would a regex work to also remove everything in between pairs of brackets, i.e. `[caption stuff] remove this text [/caption]`

Comment: /\[cap.*?tion\]/

Comment: @PoulBak, Nice! That works perfectly. There are other instances of [ ] that don't use caption, so the regex that doubles the match will work. Thanks!

Comment: @SvenLiivak that regex is very greedy and also deletes text outside of the [].

Comment: @Sven, you should escape the Square brackets.

Comment: @PoulBak It doesn't have to be `/` surrounding regex, it can be any character (at least in PHP). So for example `@\[.*?\].*\[.*?\]@` will work as well. Just for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

the above code is working for me except I have used a little tweak. This regular Expression is for removing visual composer short codes.

```
add_filter('timber/twig', function($twig) {
    $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_StringLoader()); 
    $twig->addFilter(
      new Twig_SimpleFilter(
        'strip_square_brackets',  
         function($string) {
            $regexExp = "/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]/";
             $string = preg_replace($regexExp, '', $string);
             return $string;
            } 
        )
    ); 
    return $twig;
 });
```

and in twig file:

```
{{post.content|strip_square_brackets}}
```

Tweak is:

```
$regexExp = "/\[(\/*)?vc_(.*?)\]/";
$string = preg_replace($regexExp, '', $string);
```